# inserting a number value with comma

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `MVC` application, written in `C#`, that stores student cotes in a database.
A student's cote may be `20/20`, `11/20`, `12.3/20`

The teacher must write this value in a form input and then submit the form.

All is okay with numbers that don't have a comma. But each time I try to insert 12.3 in the form field, I get this error message:

> "The value 12.3 is not valid for StudentCot"

I changed the type of `StudentCot (decimal, float,  double )` without  success.

Does a notation datatype for numbers with comma exist? Any idea? Please help, I would like something like this

```
 //...
  //[DataType(DataType.NumberWithComma)]
public float StudentCot{get;set;}
```

The table field type is real(sql server)

Comment: Cote: A shelter for mammals or birds, esp. pigeons.  Comma: 1. A punctuation mark (,) indicating a pause between parts of a sentence.

Comment: You might have to go with `string` or do some custom validation manipulation before insertion.

Comment: thanks! I went with string and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are "," uses in current culture/ you can try change Culture in Thread.CurrentThread.Culture or change "." to "," before send it to parse

Answer (score 0):

The validation uses the `culture info` from the current `thread`.
This is probably set to a comma for the decimal sign.

If you will only accept a dot for the decimal sign, you can set your application to run under a culture that uses the dot as a decimal sign.

You can do that using a line of code in each request

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

or you can put it in the web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

If you want to allow dots and commas you have to make the field a string and do the validation and conversion on the server.

Comment: That is because MVC doesn't validate the numeric input, so now that's up to you to do! If you ONLY want the dot as decimal sign, i'd advice you to set the cluture. It's one line of code in the web.config. This then validates all numeric input with the dot as decimal sign, but it also output formats the numbers when you do a ToString()